# MS Graph API restrict result by Administrative units

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I wrote a powershell script that comunicate with Microsoft Graph API. All works as I expected.

But is there any way how to restrict result by Azure Administrative units?

I have more companies in the tenant and the app has to access only to users of one company.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid we can't. When we request microsoft graph api, we can use `$filter=fieldName eq 'xxx'` to filter the results. But the field `companyName` is unsupported query filter when request the users.

[image]